# Error ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-11-12 04:08:13:427 in python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert these values to datetime type but I keep getting an error.

```
0        2021-11-12 04:08:13:427
17       2021-11-12 04:13:15:044
34       2021-11-12 04:18:17:817
51       2021-11-12 04:23:19:887
68       2021-11-12 04:28:21:409
```

the code i used:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

the error:

> Error ParserError: Unknown string format: 2021-11-12 04:08:13:427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mentioning format. The values also seem to have some trailing spaces.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].str.strip(), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
```

Comment: i get this error: ValueError: unconverted data remains: :427

Comment: Seems like there are some trailing spaces with values. Use strip().